# Why backspace doesn't go to the previous page in firefox/xfce4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, firefox

I have a big problem, when I hit `backspace` while web browsing with firefox under xfce4 debian it doesn't go to the previous page like it's used to do under windows, any idea how to fix this annoying behavior?

Comment: why: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=262905 . (i searched "debian firefox backspace" in google, and from 10th result, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358764 , navigated there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the address bar write `about:config` and hit enter.

Then search for *backspace* and double click on the `browser:backspace_action` entry.

In the pop-up window change value from `2` to `0` and from now on your backspace will go to the previous webpage.

Just for the reference, possible values are:

- `0`: Backspace goes to the previous page
- `1`: Backspace scrolls up the page
- `2`: Backspace key does nothing